# fullcalendar change resourcesEvents depending on view

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make a calendar that changes resources event depending on view.
I'll explain, I'm loading the events with AJAX jQuery

```
getEvents(view){
  var param;
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: '/calendar/get_events.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'view=' + view,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) { }
  });

  return request;
}
```

The return values depending on the view. How can I change the events when I change the view?

I apologize for my english and I thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: By using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getView you can ask fullCalendar what the name of the current view is. Does that help? P.S. Your English is perfect, based on what you've written above :-)

Comment: Thank you so much ADyson, do you think I can to change the events with "getView"? I have read the documentation and from what I understand it's not possible to change events during the session. I have to reload different events whenever I change view.

Comment: If you define your events using this pattern: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function then fullCalendar will (as that documentation mentions) automatically re-run the callback function you provide whenever the user changes the date range or switches views